# Procedure or function InOut has too many arguments specified

Tags: sql, sql-server

One of our vendors recently performed a server update for our security system (badge readers, door accessibility, door access reporting, etc.). The contractor only backed up half of the SQL database (omitted database CCFTEvent; bush league) that this system and our site uses on the front-end for reporting. Now, one of the reports that we widely use to monitor door access in/out is borked. I'm new to SQL and the original developer who helped bridge/code the gap between this security system and our front-end is long gone. I am hoping for some help or guidance from the fine people on this site.

Some of the developers of the security system we use tried to mock up what they "think" it was but it's obvious incorrect. Below is the code they provided us but it does not work.

```
> //** Stored Procedure dbo.InOut located in database CCFTEvent **//

USE [CCFTEvent]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[InOut]    Script Date: 1/17/2023 2:45:15 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author:      Name
-- Create date: 
-- Description: 
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InOut]


    @nameOPID nvarchar(120) = ''

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
          ch.LastName
        , ch.FirstName
        , ctfti.Name AS [CardType]/*, ctfti.Description*/
        , c.EncodedNumber AS [CardNumber]


    FROM Cardholder AS ch
    JOIN Card as c
        ON CardholderID = FTItemID
    JOIN CardType as ct
        ON FTItemID = CardTypeID
    Left JOIN PersonalData as opid
        ON opid.CardholderID = CardholderID
        AND opid.PersonalDataFieldID = 672
    Left JOIN PersonalData as pdsso
        ON sso.CardholderID = CardholderID
        AND sso.PersonalDataFieldID = 728



    JOIN CardholderLocation as chl
        ON chl.cardholderID = ch.FTItemID
    JOIN FTItem as chfti
        on ch.FTItemID = chfti.ID
    JOIN FTItem as ctfti
        ON ctfti.ID = ct.FTItemID
    WHERE
        c.IsEnabled = 1 --Hide Inactive users
    AND ch.LastName like CONCAT('%', @nameOPID, '%')
    OR ch.FirstName like CONCAT('%', @nameOPID, '%')
    OR convert(nvarchar, pdopid.value) like CONCAT('%', @nameOPID, '%')
    ORDER BY  /*chl.AccessTime DESC, */
        ch.LastName, ch.FirstName, OPID, c.EncodedNumber

END
```

```
> //** EmployeeTransactions.aspx.cs File **//

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="EmployeeTransactions.aspx.cs" Inherits="GallagherReports.EmployeeTransactions"  %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Employee Transactions</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <!--
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" integrity="sha256-rByPlHULObEjJ6XQxW/flG2r+22R5dKiAoef+aXWfik=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/w/bs4/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.css"/>
    -->
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap.min.css" />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jquery-ui.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/datatables.min.css"/>
    
    <style>
        
        h1.header-style {
            margin-bottom: 30px;
        }
        h2.header-style {
            color: #999;
            font-size: 24px;
            letter-spacing: 3px;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        
        .container > .row {
            margin-top: 30px;
        }
        
        #picture img {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
        
    </style>
    
    <!--
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-KM512VNnjElC30ehFwehXjx1YCHPiQkOPmqnrWtpccM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.3/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js" integrity="sha256-gQzieXjKD85Ibbpg4l8GduIagpt4oUSQRYaDaLd+8sI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/w/bs4/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js"></script>
    -->
    <script src="lib/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/datatables.min.js"></script>
    
    <script>

        // Attaches the DataTable plugin to a GridView
        function setDataTable($, table, options) {
            // Ensure the element is a non-empty table
            if ($(table).is("table") && $(table + " tr").length > 1) {
                // Move the first GridView row to a table header element. Otherwise, DataTable will throw an error.
                $(table).prepend('<thead></thead>');
                $(table + ' tr:first').appendTo(table + ' thead');
                
                // Initiate DataTable
                $(table).DataTable(options);
            }
        }
        
        // Trigger the validator when startDate changes
        function onchangeStartDate() {
            ValidatorValidate(document.getElementById('<%= dateRangeValidator.ClientID %>'));
        }
        
        // Validate the dates such that startDate occurs before endDate
        function validateDateTimes(sender, args) {
            var fromText = document.getElementById('<%= startDate.ClientID %>').value;
            var toText = document.getElementById('<%= endDate.ClientID %>').value;
            var fromDate = new Date(fromText);
            var toDate = new Date(toText);
            
            if (fromDate.getTime() <= toDate.getTime())
                args.IsValid = true;
            else
                args.IsValid = false;
        }
    
        $(document).ready(function($) {
            // Apply the DataTable plugin to the gridviews
            setDataTable($, '#cardholderInformation', {
                "info": false
            });
            setDataTable($, '#operatorInformation table', {
                "info": false,
                "paging": false,
                "ordering": false
            });
            
            
            // Initialize the datepickers
            $('.datetimefield').datetimepicker({
                controlType: 'select',
                timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss',
                showTimepicker: false
            });
            
            //Set the default dates
            if ($('#startDate').val().length + $('#endDate').val().length < 1) {
                let today = new Date();
                let lastweek = new Date();
                lastweek.setDate(lastweek.getDate() - 7);
                let startDate = $.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy", lastweek)
                let endDate = $.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy", today)
                $('#startDate').val(startDate);
                $('#endDate').val(endDate);
            }           
            
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        

        <asp:HiddenField ID="badgeNumber" runat="server" Value="" />

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            
                <div class="col-12">
                    <h1 class="header-style">Employee Lookup</h1>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="test1" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <asp:CustomValidator id="dateRangeValidator"
                               ControlToValidate="endDate"
                               Display="Static"
                               ErrorMessage="End date must occur on or after the start date."
                               ForeColor="Red"
                               OnServerValidate="dateRangeValidator_ServerValidate"
                               ClientValidationFunction="validateDateTimes"
                               ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup"
                               runat="server"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="nameOPID" Columns="4" MaxLength="30" Text="" runat="server" cssclass="form-control" placeholder="Last name or OPID" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="startDate" Columns="4" MaxLength="30" Text="" runat="server" cssclass="form-control datetimefield" onchange="onchangeStartDate()" placeholder="Start Date" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto text-center" style="padding-top: 8px;">
                            &nbsp;to&nbsp;
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="endDate" Columns="4" MaxLength="30" Text="" runat="server" cssclass="form-control datetimefield" placeholder="End Date" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <asp:button id="nameOPIDsubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="Button1_click" cssclass="btn btn-primary"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <h2 class="header-style">Cardholders</h2>
                    <asp:GridView id="cardholderInformation" 
                        runat="server" 
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                        CellPadding="4" 
                        CellSpacing="0" 
                        DataSourceID="SelectCardholderInformation"
                        ShowFooter="False"  
                        CssClass="table table-sm" 
                        EmptyDataText="Please enter an employee's first, last, or OPID."
                        showheader="true"
                        onrowcommand="GridViewButtonClick">
                            <Columns>
                          
                                <asp:ButtonField CommandName="selectCard" HeaderText="" text="Select" controlstyle-cssclass="btn btn-sm btn-primary" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="firstName"  HeaderText="First Name"  />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="lastName"  HeaderText="Last Name"  />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="CardNumber"  HeaderText="Card Number" ItemStyle-CssClass="hide-display" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hide-display" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="CardHolderID" HeaderText = "operatorID" ItemStyle-CssClass="hide-display" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hide-display" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="OPID"  HeaderText="OPID"  />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="SSO"  HeaderText="SSO"  />



                            </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                    
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                    <div id="picture" runat ="server" class="flex-item"></div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                    <div>
                        <asp:Panel ID="operatorInformation" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                
            </div>
        </div>

        <asp:SqlDataSource 
            ID="SelectCardholderInformation" 
            runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings: GALGCENTRAL %>" 
            OnSelecting="SelectCardholderInformation_Selecting"
            SelectCommand="
            execute dbo.SelectCardholderInformation
            @nameOPID = @nameOPID
            "
            >
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="nameOPID" Name="nameOPID" DefaultValue="" PropertyName="Text" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="startDate" Name="startDate" DefaultValue="" PropertyName="Text" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="endDate" Name="endDate" DefaultValue="" PropertyName="Text" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>     


        <asp:SqlDataSource 
            ID="SqlInOut" 
            runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GALGEVENTS %>" 
            OnSelecting="SqlInOut_Selecting"
            SelectCommand="
                exec dbo.InOut @card_No=@CardNumber, @startDate = @startDate, @endDate = @endDate
            ">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="badgeNumber" Name="CardNumber" PropertyName="Value" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="startDate" Name="startDate" DefaultValue="" PropertyName="Text" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="endDate" Name="endDate" DefaultValue="" PropertyName="Text" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

[Error message received on the front-end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQdjn.jpg)

Comment: Post the .NET code that calls this procedure.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance David but where can I locate this information?

Comment: It's in the source code for the "Gallagher" web application.  You can also see the request using SQL Server Profiler.

Comment: I'm new to using SQL Server Profiler, so I'll have to tinker with it some more. I updated the post with the HTML/CSS from the front-end. Will that suffice or is that still not what you are looking for?

Comment: Since the procedure name `InOut` occurs nowhere in the HTML you've posted, it's easy to infer this is not what you're looking for. This is the front-end code; you need the back-end code. The code betrays we're dealing with a classic ASP.NET application; you're looking for `.cs` or `.vb` files.

Comment: Based on the form input fields in the HTML I expect that the previous stored procedure had at least three parameters: a start date, an end date and the name/OPID. And potentially a badge number (which is a hidden field).

Comment: You mean that someone blew away code from your database and you want stackoverflow to help you recreate it? I think it's a bit misguided question unless we're talking restoring from backups and similar. Are there any backups?
If you have specific backup/restore or syntax questions, fine, but this is something you pay someone to help you with, ideally the "vendor" persons

Comment: I can locate the databases that contain name/OPIDs, and start/end dates. The vendor provided backup only includes half of the databases (and InOut was part of the one that they did not backup). I'm just trying to make sense of the front-end error message (displaying multiple arguments) and provide as much information as I can to figure out where we are going wrong.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - I located the .cs file for EmployeeTransactions. It has been added to this thread.

Comment: So clearly these are the parameters it is sending `exec dbo.InOut @card_No=@CardNumber, @startDate = @startDate, @endDate = @endDate` - and so the stored procedure needs three parameters `@card_No, @startDate, @endDate`

Comment: Even if you don't have database backups for some reason would the original "developer" not have put their code into source control?

Comment: I am not seeing any indications or documentation related to SCM, unfortunately.

Comment: I was able to restore the entire database CCFTEvents (which contains stored procedure dbo.InOut) from a very old backup but the issue still persists exactly as before. Is this just not salvageable?

Comment: If you provide a stored procedure that has the required parameters, the error should go away.

Comment: This stored procedure dbo.InOut is stored in database CCFTEvent. All parameters in the FROM, SELECT, and JOIN statements show unbound errors. When I change the first line to "USE [CCFTCentral]" those unbound errors seemingly go away and it is able to reference the databases some of those parameters are requesting. Yet the front-end page is still throwing errors. I know that dbo.InOut has always been in CCFTEvent. It used to work and now doesnt. It's a long shot but is there a way to code a "USE [Database] GO" statement so that it includes two databases and pulls from both Central and Events?